# OnChange need to reset the value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

On Load I got my input value 5.02, now i need to change in 6.

Now i am getting either null or 5.02.

How i can get my data is 6???

My code is:::

```
<input type="number" id="rate" class="form-control rate " th:value="${abc.rate}" placeholder="Rate" />
```

javaScript:::

```
$(".rate input[type='number']").change(function() {
    $("#rate").val(""); //i am reseting the value
    rateForA =$('#rate').val(); //but i am getting null
    console.log(rateForA);
});
```

Comment: *how i can get my data is 6?* but you changed value of input to empty.

Comment: Well what do you expect it to return when you reset the value?

Comment: Add an `alert("x")` inside the change event.  It's not activating because your selector is incorrect:  `$("input[type='number].rate").change()` - the input has class `rate`, not the input's parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help you

```
$('.rate').change(function(){
    var Num = parseFloat($(this).val());
    console.log(Math.ceil(Num));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  $("#rate ").change(function() { //target input via ID

        //we don't want to reset, we want to change value

        var myNumber = parseFloat($('#rate').val()); //get decimal value 
        var result = myNumber + 0.98; //Add numbers together

        //Or, you can round up to the nearest whole number instead of adding the numbers together
        //Thanks to @Bilbo Baggins for this method

        //var result = Math.ceil(myNumber);


        console.log(result); //result should be 6

    });
```

When you use `.val`, it's returning the value as a string instead of a number(integer) like this: "5.02"

We need it as an integer like so: 5.02 (no quotes)

So, we must then use `parseFloat()` (since you're using decimal places in your value) to get the value as an integer instead of a string.

We then either add the numbers together or you can remove the addition line and use the round up method instead to get to 6.